# ¿Cómo cambiar el fondo de una imagen de negro a transparente (u otro color)?

Tags: php, imagen

Quiero redimensionar una imagen de cualquier tamaño (p.e. a 200x200 pixeles), para eso utilizo la función [`imagecreatetruecolor`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.imagecreatetruecolor.php) sin problemas, pero cuando se utiliza con PNG o GIF con fondo transparente, el fondo se cambia a negro.

Ésta es la imagen original:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así se ve tras modificarla (con fondo negro):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo cambiar el tamaño de una imagen PNG/GIF y mantener el fondo transparente (o el color que yo quiera) utilizando PHP?

Comment: Excelente aporte, Gracias por compartirlo.-

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque es un aporte tipo "taringa"

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque no es una pregunta

Comment: Hola Shareiv, si deseas postear la solución a un problema que ya has resuelto puedes hacerlo pero para esto, primero elabora la pregunta y pon la solución en una respuesta. Revisa esto por favor: [¿Puedo responder a mi propia pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: no la primera vez que lo hago pero siempre hay una presona que me dice que así no es y al final tengo que eliminas el post

Comment: si lo hago como lo dice viene otro usuario y me dice que está mal

Comment: @Shareiv te invito a que mantengas tus aportes, lo unico que debes es hacerlo de la forma que te indica Carlos Muñoz

Comment: @Shareiv responder a tus propias preguntas es totalmente válido en Stack Overflow. Me apunto a lo que dicen Carlos Muñoz y jasilva: edita la pregunta para dejarlo en sólo la pregunta, y copia el resto de la publicación como respuesta. Creo que ésta es una excelente aportación que puede ser muy útil a otros usuarios, lo único que necesita es ajustarse mejor al formato de pregunta & respuestas del sitio.

Comment: @Shareiv, he editado tu pregunta, pero está a la espera de ser aprobada; mi cambio fue: `No hay necesidad de colocar "solución", si encontraste la solución, publica tu respuesta y acéptala.` Te recomiendo además mejorar la redacción y agregar el código. Gracias por publicar la solución y no te olvides de aceptar tu propia respuesta. Saludos.

Comment: ya asi esta mejor gente o los cambia mas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aquí dejo la solución del problema que tenía ya que la he encontrado y espero que  mi aporte sea de ayuda para la comunidad.

Para este caso se puede usar la función [`imagecolorallocatealpha`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.imagecolorallocatealpha.php) para cambiar el color que antes era transparente. Por ejemplo para que sea blanco (en lugar del negro por defecto):

```
imagecolorallocatealpha($tmp, 255, 255, 255, 1);
```

Después de la función `imagecolorallocatealpha()` ya que ésta toma la imagen PNG y le cambia el fondo, aún va a tener los bordes negros; para eso está la función [`imagefill()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.imagefill.php), para eliminar ese error. Ahora si quieren ver el código está abajo.

---

Código de la solución:

```
include 'compressImage.php';

$widthArray = array(200);
foreach($widthArray as $newwidth)
{                       
   compressImage($ext,$tmp,$path,$userID.$actual_image_name,$newwidth);
}
```

Y compressImage.php:

```
<?php
//Compress Image 
function compressImage($ext,$uploadedfile,$path,$actual_image_name,$newwidth)
{
    if($ext=="jpg" || $ext=="jpeg" )
    {
        $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($uploadedfile);
    }
    else if($ext=="png")
    {
        $src = imagecreatefrompng($uploadedfile);
    }
    else if($ext=="gif")
    {
        $src = imagecreatefromgif($uploadedfile);
    }

    list($width,$height)=getimagesize($uploadedfile);
    $newheight=($height/$width)*$newwidth;
    $tmp=imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth,$newheight);
    //-- esto rellena el color negro por el color seleccionado  
    $color = imagecolorallocatealpha($tmp, 255, 255, 255, 1);
    //-- aquí es para la transparencia del la imagen PNG    
    //imagecolortransparent($tmp, $color);
    //-- y al final aquí se elimina el color negro de los bordes    
    imagefill($tmp, 0, 0, $color);
    imagecopyresampled($tmp,$src,0,0,0,0,$newwidth,$newheight,$width,$height);
    $filename = $path.'small_'.$actual_image_name;
    //-- aquí se imprime la imagen y puedes cambiar el formato del archivo  
    imagejpeg($tmp,$filename);
    imagedestroy($tmp);
    return $filename;   
}
?>
```

**Imagen original:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Copia con el fondo blanco:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]