# ¿Cómo redimensionar una imagen en PHP?

Tags: php

¿ COMO RE-DIMENSIONAR UN IMAGEN EN PHP?

-Tengo una imagen de 1028 * 659. Y quiero que la imagen se redimensione a 300 * 200.-

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque no hay ninguna pregunta

Comment: Hola Facundo, si deseas postear la solución a un problema que ya has resuelto puedes hacerlo pero para esto, primero elabora la pregunta y pon la solución en una respuesta. Revisa esto por favor: [¿Puedo responder a mi propia pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Gracias por el aporte @Carlos Muñoz

Comment: Hola Facundo, aún no has leido el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos. Te sugiero leer [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Editala y agrega información necesaria para que los expertos te puedan ayudar.

Comment: ya @CarlosMuñoz es una pregunta ya que ayudar ok Hola Facundo yo cabo de hacer eso aqui te dejo lo que hice https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/94015/como-cambiar-el-fondo-negro-a-transparente-de-una-imagen-con-php-soluci%c3%b3n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  public function redimensionar_imagen($nombreimg, $rutaimg, $xmax, $ymax){  
        $ext = explode(".", $nombreimg);  
        $ext = $ext[count($ext)-1]; 

    if($ext == "jpg" || $ext == "jpeg")  
        $imagen = imagecreatefromjpeg($rutaimg);  
    elseif($ext == "png")  
        $imagen = imagecreatefrompng($rutaimg);  
    elseif($ext == "gif")  
        $imagen = imagecreatefromgif($rutaimg);  

    $x = imagesx($imagen);  
    $y = imagesy($imagen);  

    if($x <= $xmax && $y <= $ymax){
        //return "<center>Esta imagen ya esta optimizada para los maximos que deseas.<center>";
        return $imagen;  
    }

    if($x >= $y) {  
        $nuevax = $xmax;  
        $nuevay = $nuevax * $y / $x;  
    }  
    else {  
        $nuevay = $ymax;  
        $nuevax = $x / $y * $nuevay;  
    }  

    $img2 = imagecreatetruecolor($nuevax, $nuevay);  
    imagecopyresized($img2, $imagen, 0, 0, 0, 0, floor($nuevax), floor($nuevay), $x, $y);  
    //return "<center>La imagen se ha optimizado correctamente.</center>";
    return $img2;   
}
```

**Prueba con esta función, solo llama la funcion y pasa los parametros 
nombre, ruta de la imagen alto y ancho**

```
$nombre='imagen1';
$Path='img/section/immagen.jpg';
$alto=450;
$ancho=450;
$imagen_optimizada = $f->redimensionar_imagen($nombre, $Path, $alto, $ancho);
```

**Espero te ayude en lo particular a mi si me funciona.**

Comment: Y en qué parte de tu proyecto se supone que se guarda la imagen resultante en la función?