# problema con phpthumb

Tags: php

de verdad no acostumbro postear problemas con el codigo pero este ya tengo como 4 dias sin poderlo resolver, es cosa de un parametro que me falta pero no encuentro la solucion, en php 5.3 trabaja sin problemas pero en php 5.5 ya no me funciona, estoy trabajando con phpthumb 1.7.14 queriendo resizear una imagen a otro tamaño, la funcion es

```
function set_image_resize($filename, $width, $height) {

  $image_ext    = str_replace('.','', strtolower($this->get_filename_ext($filename)));

  require_once(DIR_MASTER_COMMON . 'includes/phpthumb/phpthumb.class.php');
  $phpThumb = new phpThumb();

  list($new_width,$new_height) = getimagesize($filename);

  if ( (($new_width < $width) && ($new_height == $height)) ||
       (($new_height < $height) && ($new_width == $width)) ) {
  } else {

    $phpThumb->setSourceFilename($filename);

    $phpThumb->setParameter('f', $image_ext);

    $phpThumb->setParameter('fltr', 'size|'. $width . '|' . $height);

    if ($phpThumb->GenerateThumbnail()) { // this line is VERY important, do not remove it!
       if ($phpThumb->RenderToFile($filename)) {

       }
    }
  }

  $phpThumb->resetObject();

  $img = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
  $bgColor = imagecolorallocate($img, 255,255,255);
  imagefill($img , 0,0 , $bgColor);

  $phpThumb->setSourceImageResource($img);

  $phpThumb->setParameter('f', $image_ext);

  $phpThumb->setParameter('fltr', 'wmi|' . $filename . '|C|100');

  if ($phpThumb->GenerateThumbnail()) { // this line is VERY important, do not remove it!
     if ($phpThumb->RenderToFile($filename)) {
        imagedestroy($img);
        return true;
     }
  }

}
```

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/94015/cómo-cambiar-el-fondo-de-una-imagen-de-negro-a-transparente-u-otro-color/94290#94290

Comment: Yo ya tuve ese error en el pasado funciona en PHP 5 HASTA 7 espero te ayude